# Fetch an array of ids instead of an array objects using a "with" statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have the following method:

```php
    public static function list()
    {
        return static::with(['links' => function($query) {
            $query->select('link_id');
        }])->get();
    }
```

That returns the following output:

```json
"objects": [
   {
      "id": 6,
      "links": [
         {
            link_id: 6,
            pivot: {
               object_id: 6,
               link_id: 6
            }
         },
         {
            link_id: 7,
            pivot: {
               object_id: 6,
               link_id: 7
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

How can I make it return an array of ids for "links" using the "link_id" field value, as in:

```json
"objects": [
   {
      "id": 6,
      "links": [6, 7]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static function list()
{
    $objects = static::with(['links' => function($query) {
        $query->select('link_id');
    }])->get();

    // Iterate through the objects and pluck the link_ids
    $result = $objects->map(function ($object) {
        return [
            'id' => $object->id,
            'links' => $object->links->pluck('link_id')->toArray(),
        ];
    });

    return $result->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```php
    public static function list()
    {
        return static::with(['links' => function($query) {
            $query->select('link_id');
        }])->get()->each(function ($model) {
            $model->links = $model->links->pluck('link_id')->toArray();
        });
    }
```